# Derivative under integral without integral by parts

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

Consider the function:
$$\varphi(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{1+t^2} \ dt$$

Continuity of $\varphi$ can be proven using Lebesgue continuity under intergral sign theorem.

I can prove that $\varphi$ is continuously differentiable for $x>0$ using integration by part.

**What could be a proof without using integration by part?**

Comment: Probably a stupid question: since you are defining a Fourier transform, can't you use some general result about it?

Comment: You could consider the improper integral $\eta(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ite^{itx}}{1+t^2}\,dt$ and show that a) $\eta$ is continuous, and b) $\varphi(y) - \varphi(x) = \int_x^y \eta(s)\,ds$ for $x,y > 0$. But integration by parts is easier, so why avoid it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Just to figure out what techniques could be pulled forward on the question. I however admit that I'm a bit racking my brain here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Laplace transform the given integral equals
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s)}{s-ix}\,ds $$
whose formal $n$-th derivative
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(s)\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{s-ix}\right)\,ds $$
is a convergent integral due to Dirichlet's test: $\sin(s)$ has a bounded primitive and $\left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{s-ix}\right|$ is decreasing towards $0$ for $s\to +\infty$. Truth to be told, this is not really different from applying integration by parts to the original integral.